# Unite several Graph objects of igraph-python including attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, igraph

I have several subgraphs that I would like to unite back into one graph, currently I save them in a dictionary like:

```
In [364]: result
Out[364]: 
{0: <igraph.Graph at 0x7f5b0f684de0>,
 1: <igraph.Graph at 0x7f5b0f684af8>,
 2: <igraph.Graph at 0x7f5b0f517050>,
 3: <igraph.Graph at 0x7f5b0f517148>,
 4: <igraph.Graph at 0x7f5b0f517240>}
```

Each one of these subgraphs have a the attribute `ind`:

```
In [367]: result[1].vs['name']
Out[367]: ['633', '634', '971']

In [368]: result[2].vs['name']
Out[368]: ['637']
```

But when I try to unite them into one igraph.Graph object it seems that they loose the `ind` attribute:

```
G = igraph.Graph()
G+=result[0]
G+=result[1]
G+=result[2]
G.vs["name"]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-370-72297b64297b>", line 1, in <module>
    G.vs["name"]

KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a sketch of what I am trying to do:

```
import igraph
sub1 = igraph.Graph.Full(3)
sub1.vs["name"] = ["1", "2", "3"]
sub2 = igraph.Graph.Full(2)
sub2.vs["name"] = ["4", "5"]
result = [sub1,sub2]
G = igraph.Graph()
G += result[0]
G += result[1]
G.vs["name"]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-bc406e721319>", line 1, in <module>
    G.vs["name"]

KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong here; unfortunately the Python interface does not support preserving the vertex attributes when a graph is added to another one. You have to add the attributes separately:

```
G = Graph()
G += result[0]
G += result[1]
G += result[2]
G.vs["ind"] = sum((subgraph.vs["ind"] for subgraph in result), [])
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`, and when I try `G.vs["name"] = [subgraph.vs["name"] for subgraph in result]` it seems to make a multiple copies of the attribute in `G`

Comment: Sorry, but I am keep getting the same error: `File "/home/ohm/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1820, in sum
    res = _sum_(a)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

Comment: What is the content of your `ind` vertex attribute that you are trying to carry over to the target graph?

Comment: No, I have changed the attribute from `ind` to `name`, and so I've changed the code such that the `name` attribute gets a string instead of integer. As I understood, in this way I can then find a vertex by its `name` attribute using the `find()` method.

Comment: Then you need to update the code above in your question because I can't reproduce the problem on my side.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to explain better what I'm trying to do in the code I've added to my question..

Comment: In my example, `result` is a list. In yours, `result` is a dictionary. Use `result = [sub1, sub2]` instead, and then try running `G.vs["name"] = sum((subgraph.vs["name"] for subgraph in result), [])`.